# Why do Angular (1.5) components always have an isolated scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm building an Angular library that provides a bunch of components that should make it easier to build SPA application on top of a certain API. For some components we're using the multi-slot transclusions feature. Multi-slot transclusions and components were introduces in the AngularJS 1.5 release.

I really like both features, but I don't understand why components always have an isolated scope. I would like to control how variables are accessible in my transcluded template. But now I can't, because I can't control the scope. This basically means I have to tell the users of my library to reference the parent scope first in order to get to the data they need.

Does anyone know a workaround?, or maybe I'm doing it wrong. Then please tell me :-)

So this is my component:

```
export const ProductsListComponent =
{
    transclude: {
        'template' : '?productListItemTemplate'
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/components/products-list/products-list.html',
    controller: ProductsListComponentController,
    bindings: {
        list: '='
    }
}

... 

angular.module('MyWebApplication', ['ngMessages', 'ui.router' ])
    .component( 'productList', ProductsListComponent )  

...
```

Here's the template HTML:

```
<div class="product-list-wrapper" ng-repeat="$product in $ctrl.list">
    <ng-transclude ng-transclude="template">
        <product-list-item product="$product"></product-list-item>
    </ng-transclude>
</div>
```

And this is how it can be used. And you see my problem. The expression must begin with **$parent.**$product.title, because the component scope is contained.

```
<product-list list="search.products">
    <product-list-item-template>
       <h2>{{$parent.$product.title}}</h2>
    </product-list-item-template>
</product-list>
```

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is, that using parent scope is an issue when it comes to maintainability and reusability.

Angular 2 promotes the component pattern which requires to make all outer dependencies explicit. The angular 1 component function is the way to structure your application for easier migration to angular 2.

This post is a great reference if you are interested in details about the reasons: http://teropa.info/blog/2015/10/18/refactoring-angular-apps-to-components.html#replace-ng-controller-with-component-directive

Comment: Right. But this feels like a catch-22. I would like to use the component pattern to prepare for Angular 2, but it basically looks I can only achieve my goal when using directives for now, not really the Angular 2 way.

Comment: I think there should be a way to split your existing component into several ones and get rid of the transclusion by passing the desired values down into the child components. Does that make any sense?

Comment: I guess I could refactor the ng-repeat inside the transclusion template. But the goal of my library is to abstract all the API calling for my end-users.

If there is a way to bind $product to the template than that would be the most elegant solution. But I guess this can only be done with directives in the compile method.