# How to set scope for AngularJS component

Tags: angularjs-scope, angularjs-components

Suppose I build an AngularJS component

```
function FooController($scope, $element, $attrs, $http) {
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.bar = "WIBBLE";
}

angular.module("app").component("foo", {
    templateUrl: "/app/components/foo.html",
    controller: FooController,
    transclude: true
}
```

with a template like this that contains a transclusion tag with fallback content

```
[<ng-transclude>{{$ctrl.bar}}</ng-transclude>]
```

and I use it in a page like this

```
<foo></foo>
```

then the fallback content executes in the control scope and I get this

```
[WIBBLE]
```

But if I provide the same stuff via transclusion

```
<foo>{{$ctrl.bar}}</foo>
```

then the transcluded content has a new isolate scope and `$ctrl.bar` doesn't resolve so I get

```
[]
```

### How do I set the appropriate scope?

For a directive I would define the `link` function and use the `transclude` function  to set the scope but `component` doesn't support the `link` function so I can't do that.

[Why do Angular (1.5) components always have an isolated scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771690/why-do-angular-1-5-components-always-have-an-isolated-scope?rq=1) suggests that it's flat out impossible and the answer is to use a directive instead. If that's so I'm not sure what the point of components is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just plain cannot do this for a component. Refactor it as a directive and provide a link function that supplies the directive scope to the transclude function.

```
        transclude: true, // support <ng-transclude> in the template
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {
            var transclusionElement = element.find("ng-transclude");
            transclude(scope, function (clone, scope) {
                // link element parameter is a jQuery element
                transclusionElement.html(""); // wipe the slate
                transclusionElement.append(clone); // write the content
                // DO NOT TRY TO BE CLEVER LIKE THIS
                // transclusionElement.html(clone.html());
            });
        },
```